# Unable to login with Spring security -Annotation based configuration with external database

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, maven, spring-security

I am configuring spring security following these [1](http://sivalabs.in/2014/03/springmvc4-spring-data-jpa-springsecurity-configuration-using-javaconfig/) [2](http://websystique.com/springmvc/springmvc-hibernate-many-to-many-example-annotation-using-join-table/) links.My problem is default login page of spring security is not rendering in my application ie I am able to hit all the url.Have I missed any thing Below is my configuration.

`WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` Implementaion-

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Autowired
    private DataSource dataSource;

    @Autowired
    private CustomUserDetailsService customUserDetailsService;

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder registry) throws Exception {
        registry.userDetailsService(customUserDetailsService);
    }

      @Override
      public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
        web.ignoring().antMatchers("/resources/**");
      }

      @Override
      protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf().disable()
        .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/login","/login/form**","/register","/logout").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/admin","/admin/**").hasRole("ADMIN")
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
        .formLogin()
            .loginPage("/login/form")
            .loginProcessingUrl("/login")
            .failureUrl("/login/form?error")
            .permitAll();
      }
}
```

`UserDetailsService` Implemtation

```
@Component
public class CustomUserDetailsService implements UserDetailsService
{
    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String userName) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        User user = userService.findUserByEmail(userName);
        if(user == null){
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException("UserName "+userName+" not found");
        }
        return new SecurityUser(user);
    }
}
```

`User` Implementation-

```
public class SecurityUser extends User implements UserDetails
{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    public SecurityUser(User user) {
        if(user != null)
        {
            this.setId(user.getId());
            this.setName(user.getName());
            this.setEmail(user.getEmail());
            this.setPassword(user.getPassword());
            this.setDob(user.getDob());
            this.setRoles(user.getRoles());
        }       
    }

    @Override
    public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {

        Collection<GrantedAuthority> authorities = new ArrayList<>();
        List<Role> userRoles = this.getRoles();

        if(userRoles != null)
        {
            for (Role role : userRoles) {
                SimpleGrantedAuthority authority = new SimpleGrantedAuthority(role.getRoleName());
                authorities.add(authority);
            }
        }
        return authorities;
    }

    @Override
    public String getPassword() {
        return super.getPassword();
    }

    @Override
    public String getUsername() {
        return super.getEmail();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonExpired() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonLocked() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isCredentialsNonExpired() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEnabled() {
        return true;
    }   
}
```

And my `SpringWebAppInitializer` class is-

```
public class SpringWebAppInitializer extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer{

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses()
    {
        return new Class<?>[] {  AppConfig.class };
    }

    @Override
    protected String[] getServletMappings()
    {
        return new String[] { "/" };
    }

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses()
    {
        return new Class<?>[] { AppConfig.class};
    }



    @Override
    protected Filter[] getServletFilters() {
       return new Filter[]{ 
               new DelegatingFilterProxy("springSecurityFilterChain"),
               new OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter()};
    } 

}
```

Moreover I tried with my custom login page,even this is not rendering as well-

```
<form:form id="loginForm" method="post" action="${appUrl}/controller/login"
                    modelAttribute="user" class="register" role="form">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="">
                            <input type="text" id="username" name="username"
                                class="form-control register-input" placeholder="UserName" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="">
                            <input type="password" id="password" name="password"
                                class="form-control register-input" placeholder="Password" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <input type="hidden" name="${_csrf.parameterName}"  value="${_csrf.token}" />
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="col-sm-offset-3">
                            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Login">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form:form>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to using the default spring login page, you doesn't to put :

```
.formLogin()
        .loginPage("/login/form")  <--- this line is not needed for default spring login
        .loginProcessingUrl("/login")
        .failureUrl("/login/form?error")
        .permitAll(); <--- and this no need too
```

From your configuration above,you are using your own login page.
Another thing is your form login.

Please take note if you are using tag `form`, you need to use it on input also.

Example:

```
<form:form modelAttribute="foo" method="post" ...
<form:input type="text" id="username" path="username" ....
```

by using tag `form`,you need to include `modelAttribute=""` and call it in the controller as `@ModelAttribute("foo") Users users` and you should notice that tag `form` doesn't use `name` in `<input>` instead they are using `path`.

But,you also can use a normal form without tag `form` and if you are using this, no need to include the `modelAttribute=""` and use it as a normal form.

If your spring security doesn't trigger or you can still click anywhere,it's because the `SpringWebAppInitializer` doesn't load your security config and its doesn't know either the config exist or not. I suggest you to lookup for `WebApplicationInitializer`.